# Necesito Eliminar los salto de Linea de un word en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion web que me hace un merge de varios documentos word pero necesito unirlos **sin los salto de Linea o ENTER**, lo estoy desarrollando en c# ya tengo el merge de documentos pero solo me falta eliminar los **saltos de linea**, logre trabajarlo con la libreria interop.word.dll me funciona como quiero pero al momento de publicarlo me da un error con la interoperabilidad del word y no he podido resolver ese problema en mi servidor windows 2012, por ese motivo estoy viendo otra opcion, Gracias de antemano

Este es el metodo que hace el merge de varios documentos word:

```
public static void Merge(string[] filesToMerge, string outputFilename, bool insertPageBreaks, string documentTemplate, string nsec_aop, DataTable tblRequisitos)
    {
        object defaultTemplate = documentTemplate;
        object missing = System.Type.Missing;
        object pageBreak = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
        object outputFile = outputFilename;

        object oTrue = true;
        object oAll = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

        // Create a new Word application
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        try
        {
            // Create a new file based on our template
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(
                                          ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);

            // Make a Word selection object.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;

            //Count the number of documents to insert;
            int documentCount = filesToMerge.Length;

            //A counter that signals that we shoudn't insert a page break at the end of document.
            int breakStop = 0;

            // Loop thru each of the Word documents
            foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
            {
                breakStop++;
                // Insert the files to our template
                selection.InsertFile(
                                            file
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing
                                        , ref missing);


                selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
                selection.Find.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;


                object oFindText = "\r";
                object oReplaceText = " ";
                selection.Find.Execute(ref oFindText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref oReplaceText, ref oAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                oFindText = "  ";
                oReplaceText = " ";
                selection.Find.Execute(ref oFindText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref oReplaceText, ref oAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                oFindText = "\n";
                oReplaceText = " ";
                selection.Find.Execute(ref oFindText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref oReplaceText, ref oAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                oFindText = "\t";
                oReplaceText = " ";
                selection.Find.Execute(ref oFindText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref oReplaceText, ref oAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                oFindText = "\v";
                oReplaceText = " ";
                selection.Find.Execute(ref oFindText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref oReplaceText, ref oAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                oFindText = "\r\n";
                oReplaceText = " ";
                selection.Find.Execute(ref oFindText, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref missing, ref oTrue, ref oReplaceText, ref oAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                /*
                //Do we want page breaks added after each documents?
                if (insertPageBreaks && breakStop != documentCount)
                {
                    selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);
                }*/
            }

            // Save the document to it's output file.
            wordDocument.SaveAs(
                            ref outputFile
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing
                        , ref missing);


            // Clean up!
            wordDocument.Close();
            wordDocument = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //I didn't include a default error handler so i'm just throwing the error
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Finally, Close our Word application
            wordApplication.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        }
    }
```

Y este es el error que me lanza cuando esta publicado en el servidor windows server 2012 y tambien esta instalado el office 2013

```
    [UnauthorizedAccessException]: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.AllocateUninitializedObject(RuntimeType objectType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateInstance(RuntimeType serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at SGPJ.DescargarArchivo.Merge(String[] filesToMerge, String outputFilename, Boolean insertPageBreaks, String documentTemplate, String nsec_aop, DataTable tblRequisitos)
   at SGPJ.DescargarArchivo.GenerarProtocolo3(String nsecAop)
   at SGPJ.DescargarArchivo.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[HttpUnhandledException]: Exception of type &#39;System.Web.HttpUnhandledException&#39; was thrown.
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
```

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido Nery, tu pregunta necesita estar mejor redactada: Coloca el código que tienes, especifica la manera en que podemos reproducir tu escenario, agrega los errores que tienes al momento de ponerlo en el servidor. También ve a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que tengas la oportunidad de aprender cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya mejore la pregunta espero que este mas claro

Answer (score 0):

Bueno te puedo guiar en la dirección correcta, pero va a necesitar de trabajo de tu parte (Tengo mucho trabajo ahora), pero te voy a explicar como modificar manualmente un archivo de word...

Te explico como funciona, acabo de crear este archivo en word con saltos de linea:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los guardo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y le cambio la extensión de .docs a .zip
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora abro el archivo zip y busco el archivo document.xml dentro de la carpeta word
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si abres el archivo document.xml:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La línea resaltada es un salto de línea

Ve intentando armar tu código para que hagan esto de forma automática y publica tus resultados.

Intentaré estar pendiente de esta pregunta para ayudar en tu progreso.

Suerte!

Comment: es mil veces mejor colocar el texto del código que una imagen. De esta manera aumentas la calidad de tu respuesta y facilitas la ayuda a más personas :D

Comment: estimado muchas gracias por la respuesta, eso mismo he pensado manejarlo a nivel de XML, eliminando las etiquetas <P> sin que afecte al formato aplicado en ese texto